# Can't get two different buttons to call two different functions with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

```
<div class="card">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Completed</span>
      <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="button" ng-click="setActive('Yes')" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('Yes')}">Yes</button>
        <button class="button" ng-click="setActive('No')" ng-class="{'button-positive': isActive('No')}">No</button>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>


.controller('CompleteWorkOrderController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.active = 'No';

    $scope.setActive = function(value){
        $scope.active = value;
    }

    $scope.isActive = function(value){
        return value === $scope.active;
    }
});
```

For some reason, no matter what I do, either button will send the value 'Yes' to the setActive() function.

Code is pulled right off of this simple and functioning [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HmuTStz70x5KoAvLaP4?p=preview), I can't at all understand what's wrong. If I dump this into my own Plunker it works just fine as well.

Any idea? I'm genuinely mystified right now.

```
 .state('tab.complete-work-order', {
  url: '/complete-work-order/:workOrderId',
  views: {
    'tab-timesheet': {
      templateUrl: 'timesheet/templates/complete-work-order.html',
      controller: 'CompleteWorkOrderController'
    }
  }
})
```

This is how the controller gets set to this page. It seems to work fine since the function gets called.

Comment: Can we get a link to your broken plunker? Where in the markup do you set `ng-controller="CompleteWorkOrderController"` ?

Comment: The plunker works fine, it's in my own code that it isn't working properly. I don't set ng-controller in the markup, I just use the router to get the proper controller. The function gets called, it just only ever uses the value set on that first button. I've made sure there isn't any weird HTML overlap where it's actually clicking the first button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's the:

```
<label class="item item-input">
```

I guess Ionic takes this to mean the entire thing is a single input, and somehow just uses the value from the first button?

Not sure how that happens, but mystery solved at least.

Comment: Even with <label > only it is happening, I thought it was something related to the class item but it is not. Great catch!

Answer (score 0):

The html page might be cached in the browser, clear the cache and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't it. I really can't understand what's going on here

Comment: I can not see problem anywhere in your code. Try changing the html file name to check the behaviour. I am sure it should be something with the caching as you are properly wiring the controller to the template. Good luck.